# New Neptune 3 Max. Cubic infill problems. Flexible Flashforge PLA

Tags: print-quality, infill, elegoo-neptune-3

[image: Image of ragged cubic infill]Using settings and filament (Flashforge Flexible PLA) that work well on my Ender S1, I am having trouble with cubic infill on the Neptune 3 max.  I was wondering if you could offer some advice.  The cubic infill becomes very ragged.  (See picture).  When I use grid infill it is better but still a little ragged.  I am printing pretty slowly at 50.  I have calculated E-steps.  I was thinking I could raise the z-offset but I calculated this during leveling and the bottom and top layers look great.  Any help would be appreciated.